# Make Visual Studio use a SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-2012

I have a RHEL Linux instance with MySQL running. I have the connectors and I'm trying to setup a new connection to the database in Visual Studio 2012. Problem is, it's on a corporate remote server and the connection needs to be done via SSH. I can connect through Putty or MySQL Workbench, how can I tell Visual Studio to connect from the tunnel on either Putty or Workbench?

Comment: Look into ssh tunneling. See [MySQL connection over SSH tunnel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373366/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel-how-to-specify-other-mysql-server) and [Connecting to MYSQL over SSH tunnel](http://serverfault.com/questions/517081/connecting-to-mysql-over-ssh-tunnel)

Answer (score 1):

I setup the SSH Tunnel properly, but found out that I had the mysqld service running on my machine. As soon as I shut that off and setup the tunnel again I successfully added the tunneled connection to Visual Studio as a Database connection.